# Passing objects from JDialog back to root frame

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jframe, jdialog

Let's say we have a JFrame `frame` that contains two JPanels, `buttonPanel` and `dataPanel`, and in this panel a single JButton `button`. When clicked, `button` creates and shows a JDialog `dialog` in its own window (as usual). Using several JTextFields and a submit button, the JDialog `dialog` creates a new Object `dataObject` encapsulating these input data.  If we wish our `dataPanel` JPanel in the main application `frame` to display this `dataObject`, how should `dataObject` be appropriately passed to the JPanel residing in a foreign JFrame?

That was a mouthful even to me while writing it, so I'll attempt to clarify:

JFrame `frame`

- JPanel `dataPanel` - meant to display data from Objects created in the JDialog
- JPanel `buttonPanel` - contains a button to open the JDialog, into which some information will be entered and with said information our Object `dataObject` is constructed.

The goal here is to pass this `dataObject` (and it's constituent fields) to the `dataPanel` to be displayed.  What is the most appropriate way to handle this? I considered keeping the Objects in `dataPanel` static and then calling a static method from the JDialog to add the new object, but it doesn't seem the proper thing to do.

Some guidance?

Comment: Downvoted, so I assume I did something wrong. But what about the question was bad? I attempted to explain something that is extremely abstract to me; sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much will depend on the structure of your program, including how the dialog is supposed to behave:

- If the JDialog is *modal* and disappears when the submit button has been pushed, then the solution is easy -- extract the data from the dialog-related class after it returns which will be the line of code right after where you display the dialog. The dialog's submit JButton's listener could simply make the dialog no longer visible.
- Otherwise if the JDialog is *non-modal* and disappears when the submit button has been pushed, then you may wish to attach a Listener to its Window, I believe a WindowListener, and then have your calling code extract the information when the listener indicates that the dialog has been closed or is closing.
- Otherwise, if the JDialog is *non-modal* and is not supposed to become invisible when the submit button has been pressed but you need to update the calling program with new data, then I would have the calling class add a PropertyChangeListener onto the dialog-related class so that the dialog-related class can notify any listeners that submit has been pressed. This code would be in the dialog's submit JButton's listener.
- I would give a dialog-related class a `public DataObject getDataObject()` method that the calling code can call once the dialog returns, allowing the class that displays the dialog to extract the pertinent information when needed.
- Whatever you do, there is no reason to use static fields and many reasons not to. I strongly urge you to not even consider this.

For example of a *modal* dialog that returns:

```
// caveat: code has not been tested by compilation or running. 
JButton myButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Dialog Button") {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    MyDialogPanel myDialogPanel = new MyDialogPanel();
    JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(myJFrame, "My Dialog", 
            ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    myDialog.add(myDialogPanel);
    myDialog.pack();
    myDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(myJFrame);
    myDialog.setVisible(true);

    // dialog now returns and we can get the data
    // assuming that the wrapper object for your data 
    // is called "DataObject"
    DataObject dataObject = myDialogPanel.getDataObject();

    // and perhaps use it. Assume setDataObject is a method 
    // of the main GUI that displays the data object
    setDataObject(dataObject);
  }
});
```

Comment: I went with a nested class solution.  You got me off the static path and onto the correct one though, thank you!

Comment: @CannonPalms: you're welcome. Yep, you will want avoid use of statics unless absolutely essential. Glad you've got things working.